# Django admin, show only needed models

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, admin

I'm new to django and I need to show only those models in admin, which have status = 'pending'.

```
ITEM_STATUSES = (
    ('pending', _('Waiting approval')),
    ('approved', _('Approved')),
    ('declined', _('Declined'))
)

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=ITEM_STATUSES)
    ...

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) (for django>=1.6) method of your `ModelAdmin`:

> The `get_queryset` method on a ModelAdmin returns a QuerySet of all
>   model instances that can be edited by the admin site.

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ItemAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(status='pending')
```

FYI, for django <= 1.5 use [`queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset) method instead.